# Query firstname in created_by of adminuser in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I am building a simple blog, and I therefore want to query who wrote the article.
However, I am not allowed to query firstname when its an admin user

```
Cannot query field \"firstname\" on type \"AdminUser\
```

How do I circumvent this, and what is best practice here?

Comment: How are you quering the admin user? share code?

Comment: Please show us your attempt